# ElastiCache doesn't show automated backups

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elasticache

We are using AWS ElastiCache and we have configured it to get automated backups. It seems that the automated backups are missing from the UI though. I am attaching the following screenshot, any idea why? Is it a bug on AWS UI?
[image]

Comment: Assume it is redis? is automated backup enabled while creating the redis cache node/cluster? If yes, is it visible on describe_snapshots cli/api call

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It seems the automated backup is working as I can see the snapshot from the aws console and it continues to do them. But I don't see them on the AWS UI so it might be a bug there.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in aws UI

To view all backups: select from Filter `All BackUps` type `automatic.large`or the type of your instance and `hit enter`

Or by using the console:

`$ aws elasticache describe-snapshots --max-records 20`

Comment: Yes it seems there is a AWS UI bug. Seems like if there is some automated backup failure, you can't see the automated backups in the AWS UI. I can see the new backups which was created after the failed automated backup though (and only them) in the AWS UI. I can see all of them though in the console with the above command.